# japp.jar is not found when building docker image

Tags: java, docker

I'm very much new to docker. I have a node application that process/read a java file. I'm trying to create a docker image that runs node and java. I node configs are working well but I'm always getting errors when building the docker file because of java - it shows

```
failed to compute cache key: "/japp.jar" not found: not found"
```

My Dockerfile contains:

```sh
FROM node:14.18.1 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
WORKDIR /code
EXPOSE 8443
COPY package.json /code/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . /code

# Jave Config

FROM eclipse-temurin:11
RUN mkdir /opt/app
COPY japp.jar /opt/app
ENTRYPOINT  ["java", "-jar", "/opt/app/japp.jar"]

CMD ["node","app.js"]
```

I was trying to follow the docs [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin) but no luck.

In the past, I was using the following for Java config and that was working fine, but it shows some vulnerability so I need to switch to eclipse-temurin:11

```
# RUN echo 'deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && \
#     apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jre-headless && \
#     apt-get clean;
```

Comment: On your host system, where is the file `japp.jar`?  (In the same directory as the Dockerfile, or somewhere else?)  Note that you can't use multiple `FROM` lines to combine images, so your current Dockerfile _only_ contains Java and not Node; the commented-out fragment would probably work better.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks! in your experience how can I replace the commented out section with eclipse-temurin:11?

Comment: I'd probably run basically exactly the set of commands you have there.  Or do the inverse and install Node on the Java image.  Or figure out how to run the two parts in two separate containers, communicating via some network channel.